# Is there any programming language which has a for-while loop?

Tags: loops, language-features, structured-programming

This is what I mean by a for-while loop:

```
for (<init>; <update>) <body> while (<test>);
```

It roughly translates to:

```
<init>
<body>

while (<test>) {
    <update>
    <body>
}
```

This seems like a [very common programming pattern](http://www.cs.uni.edu/~wallingf/patterns/loops.html#loop-and-a-half). Yet, no language that I know of has such a control structure. Hence, a common workaround is to implement it as follows instead:

```
<init>

while (true) {
    <body>
    unless (<test>) break;
    <update>
}
```

While this works, it feels very clunky. In my humble opinion, having a conditional break in the middle of an infinite while loop goes against the spirit of structured programming.

Here's a motivational example for the need of for-while loops:

```js
function swap(arr, i, j) {
    var tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = tmp;
    return arr;
}

function heapify(heap, i) {
    var len = heap.length;

    for (var min = i; swap(heap, i, min), i = min) {
        var left  = 2 * i + 1;
        var right = 2 * (i + 1);

        if (left  < len && heap[left]  < heap[min]) min = left;
        if (right < len && heap[right] < heap[min]) min = right;
    } while (min !== i);

    return heap;
}
```

As you can see, the control is very easy to follow and the code is a lot cleaner than the workaround:

```js
function swap(arr, i, j) {
    var tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = tmp;
    return arr;
}

function heapify(heap, i) {
    var len = heap.length;
    var min = i;

    do (true) {
        var left  = 2 * i + 1;
        var right = 2 * (i + 1);

        if (left  < len && heap[left]  < heap[min]) min = left;
        if (right < len && heap[right] < heap[min]) min = right;

        if (min === i) break;
        swap(heap, i, min);
        i = min;
    }

    return heap;
}
```

Anyway, do you know of any programming language which has such a control structure? Lisp doesn't count because it's primarily functional and I'm looking for a primarily imperative programming language.

Comment: Such a *"very common programming pattern"* that I don't think I've ever seen it in my four-decade-log career?:-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Perhaps you don't write many programs that require this control structure, which is fine. However, over my decade long experience in programming I've encountered this pattern several times. It's not a very common pattern. However, I think it's common enough to warrant a new control structure.

Comment: @paxdiablo Here's a [Python Enhancement Proposal](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0315/) for a control structure similar to the one I'm describing. This shows that the programming pattern that I'm describing is indeed not uncommon.

Comment: @paxdiablo By the way, it seems like this pattern is called the [Loop and a Half](http://www.cs.uni.edu/~wallingf/patterns/loops.html#loop-and-a-half) pattern. Hence, it's indeed a very common pattern.

Comment: Why a "for-while" instead of "do-while" with an optional <update> expression?  Like `do { <body> } while (<test>; <update>);`  The "do" keyword and structure already implies execution of the <body> _before_ the test.  The "for" keyword usually implies a long-established pattern of <init> then <test> _before_ the <body>.  This doesn't change the need nor answer your question, but the keyword choice makes more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize that this isn't a completely satisfactory answer since c# does not have such a built-in control structure, but I had originally anticipated the syntax would be more concise so that it would have been nearly what you are looking for.  (It turns out that c# will not do an implicit cast of the lambda expression to a boolean function, hence the explicit "garbage" surrounding the  expression.)

That aside, the following c# code demonstrates the alternate keyword choice I mentioned in the comments:  `do { <body> } while (<test>; <update>)`.  This do-while-update syntax matches the pattern flow better than the for-while syntax you proposed.  It's already questionable that any new construct would need a special place for `<init>` (as in for loops) unless you're concerned with scope of the construct variables, but in my experience no existing do-construct offers that anyway.

```
var min = i; //<init>
do {
    //<body>
    var left = 2 * i + 1;
    var right = 2 * (i + 1);

    if (left < len && heap[left] < heap[min])
        min = left;
    if (right < len && heap[right] < heap[min])
        min = right;
} while ((min != 1) // <test>
    ? ((Func<bool>)(() => {
        swap(heap, i, min); i = min; //<update>
        return true; }))() : false);
```

Note: The ternary conditional operator ensure that the `<update>` section is executed only when `<test>` is true.